# How to load the link (or href) using java?

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I get the values from the JSP page based on the two parameters. I form a new query, and get the values from the database. Then, I add it to the `ArrayList`. After the list is added, I want to invoke the one link. How can I invoke the link in Java after complete my logic?

I'm using the struts1.2. At the same time, in the link, I want to use three parameters and `onClick` function also. Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to display the link in the JSP having some params and values in href?

Comment: please make your question clear

Comment: very vaguely described. Please add some code. (And, please take care of formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name` or the `properly` fields of a `html:link` to specify a map that will contain your parameters. See [html:link](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3alink) for more details.

You can see [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/struts-de-mystified-parts-3-4/) an example using a forward link with the name property to specify multiple arguments.

Comment: how to use the html:link in java..can you explain me in detail

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham you can use the `onclick`, but like mentioned in the documentation, you need to provide a `JavaScript event handler that is executed when this element receives a mouse click.`. From javascript you will be able to call, using an ajax if you like, a java backend.